# remove the world "Uhr" from Fullcalendar Resource timeline

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I am working with fullcalendar v5 +  Resource timeline in an Angular 10 project, to display events with resources and with

```
locale: 'de'
```

My problem is when I display "resourceTimelineDay" or "resourceTimelineWeek" the world "Uhr" is added automatically in the header as you can see in the screenshot
[image]

To gain some space I need to remove this "Uhr" from the header, I tried to use

```
views: {
  resourceTimelineWeek: { // name of view
    slotLabelFormat: [
      { weekday: 'long' }, // top level of text
      { hour: 'numeric',  omitZeroMinute: true, meridiem: false},
    ],
  },

},
```

but I couldn't find the correct way
PS: if I change the `locale: de` to `locale: 'en'`, no extra words displayed in the header
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper solution either.

The following css-hack did it for me:

```
.fc-timeline-header-row-chrono a.fc-timeline-slot-cushion.fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner {
    max-width: 3ch;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```